# PHP problem when extracting a zip file with non-latin characters in the filenames

Tags: php, utf-8, php-ziparchive

I use the following code to extract a zip file in php

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($this->abs_path);
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo($folder_abs_path);
    $zip->close();
    echo 'woot!';
} else {
    echo 'doh!';
}
```

But it does not work when the zip contains folders with non-latin characters (UTF-8) such as Greek.
The zip's name is myzip.zip.
And it contains a folder 'Νέος Φάκελος'.
When I extract it, the folder has name: îΓª¬ ¡ßí£óª¬

I want this code to include in a wordpress plugin...

Comment: If your issue is definitely within PHP (rather than an OS or other external setting) then maybe you can load [`mb_String` PHP extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) to resolve this issue

Comment: What's your PHP version? I recall having to do `iconv('UTF-8', 'CP850', $name)` or something similar before if was fixed, but the fix was released years ago.

Comment: As per [the manual](http://php.adamharvey.name/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php#refsect1-ziparchive.addfile-changelog) prior to PHP 8 you can't expect `ZipArchive` to support arbitrary extra data that may store Unicode names., or support the entry flag `0x0800`.

Comment: @AmigoJack is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? There are countless ways to achieve this, since many programs are able to support Unicode filenames. You could parse the PKZip file format yourself - see [this](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/ZIP) and [this](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).

Comment: The problem is that there is no defined encoding for filenames in the ZIP format, and no method [that I found] for defining it in the ZIP metadata. So the charset for these filenames is likely whatever the originating system is. Additionally, the fact that the "good" and "bad" versions of the filenames have the same character count implies that this is not a mixup with UTF8, but between two different single-byte encodings. Unfortunately even after puzzling over the cp850/cp1253/iso8859-7 encoding tables I can't figure out exactly which two charsets are disagreeing.

Comment: Ultimately when accepting a ZIP file you will need to explicitly know what encoding the filenames use, and then get into the middle of the extraction process to fix the encoding between the source ZIP and the destination filesystem.

Comment: If you add the following code it will produce a list of the filenames in the archive, as well as a hex-encoded version so that we can see the exact byte values: `for($i=0,$c=$zip->numFiles; $i<$c; $i++ ){ $n=$zip->statIndex($i)['name']; printf("%s %s\n", bin2hex($n), $n); }` eg: `666f6f foo` from that we should be able to deduce what the source encoding is, and from there work to figure out how get the extraction to work with the proper encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the specific zip file.
When it was created, charset was not set.

Thank you all for your answers

Comment: ZIP files cannot carry charsets to begin with. UTF-8 is the only encoding that can be achieved unambiguously.